# Is it possible to transfer one-time credit card info to a physical mag stripe card?

Tags: credit-card

Several banks allow you to generate a one-time credit card number via an app or web page, with restrictions such as maximum amount and/or short expiry date.  These are fine for online transactions but sometimes you would like to use a one-time number for an in-person transaction (eg a petrol pump or redbox machine, or for use in an environment where there is a real risk of your card being cloned).  Would writing the number/name/cvv/date to a magstripe card give you something you could swipe?

Although the implementation of this would be similar to the subject of [Is it possible to generate valid track 1 and track 2 data from basic CC info?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130509/is-it-possible-to-generate-valid-track-1-and-track-2-data-from-basic-cc-info), it is not the identical question because this usage also depends on the behaviour of the back-end systems which may be specific to use-once virtual credit cards and different from cloned regular credit cards.

Comment: Possible duplicate (albeit with a very different tone to the question) of [Is it possible to generate valid track 1 and track 2 data from basic CC info?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130509/is-it-possible-to-generate-valid-track-1-and-track-2-data-from-basic-cc-info)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Among other things, the value provided for CVV online (such as a one-time use credit card number) is a CVV2 value, similar to what's printed on the back of a Visa/Mastercard.  (And is generally used for any "Card not present" transactions.)

On the other hand "card present" transactions require the CVV1 value, which is encoded on magnetic track.  A one-time-use card on the site wouldn't provide that value, so it wouldn't be possible to build the whole magnetic stripe.

Comment: I was just typing up this same answer when you beat me to it.  :-)

Comment: Would a card which was issued with the intent of only being used in 'card not present' transactions even have its CVV1 be checked if used in a 'card present' transaction?  Is there even one stored in the back end at the bank to check against?  This may be a question that can only be answered by actually trying it :)

Comment: @GrahamToal, no, banks don't typically issue a physical card for "card not present" transactions.  So a "card not present" account-number-only doesn't have a CVV1, the bank provides only a CVV2.  And the banks' software won't validate the card if you put the CVV2 on the mag stripe, where only the CVV1 is expected.  This is deliberate to prevent this exact type of fraud.

Comment: Understood.  But just to be clear to readers, I wasn't suggesting this as a means of fraud, but to make more usable a service that the banks already offer.  I doubt they will offer physical onetime-use credit cards in the foreseeable future due to the cost and hassle of giving customers a way to update them ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can however use a number of services, which issues you a physical card that charges all transactions to another card which can be virtual. Google "prepaid charge card".